# Hive alter table statement

Tags: hadoop, hive

```
ALTER TABLE abc ADD PARTITION (year = 2014,month=1,day=1) location '/data/input/abc/year=2014/month=1/day=1';
FAILED: ParseException line 1:47 character ' ' not supported here
```

why this error is coming up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears the error is occurring because you have a space inside your partition command.

```
year = 2014
```

Try instead

```
year=2014
```

...assuming your year column is of `int`. Type.  If it's a string you'd need

```
year='2014'
```